# Rust Vec to Ruby Array with FFI Segfaults

Tags: ruby, rust, ffi, ruby-ffi

I am trying to return a struct that can be converted into a Ruby array from an external rust function but when I try to call the structs #to_a method I get a segfault.

```rust
use libc::size_t;
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Array {
    len: libc::size_t,
    data: *const libc::c_void,
}

impl Array {
    fn from_vec<T>(mut vec: Vec<T>) -> Array {

        vec.shrink_to_fit();

        let array = Array { data: vec.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_void, len: vec.len() as libc::size_t };

        mem::forget(vec);

        array
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn get_links(url: *const libc::c_char) -> Array {

  // Get links

  let mut urls: Vec<String> = vec![];

  // push strings into urls vec

  // urls => collections::vec::Vec<collections::string::String>

  Array::from_vec(urls)
}
```

```ruby
require 'ffi'

module Rust
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib './bin/libembed.dylib'

  class NodesArray < FFI::Struct
      layout :len,    :size_t, # dynamic array layout
             :data,   :pointer #

      def to_a
          self[:data].get_array_of_string(0, self[:len]).compact
      end
  end

  attach_function :get_links, [:string], NodesArray.by_value
end
```

When I try to use this function in ruby it will return the Fii::NodesArray.  I can also get the len and data off of the struct.  It is only when I call the #to_a that segfaults.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby FFI but... are `len` and `data` supposed to be reversed?  It's `data`, `len` in Rust, but `len`, `data` in Ruby.

Comment: Hmm.  Good point. However I do believe I had them in the correct layout at some point and was still segfaulting.  I will try switching that and update the question.

Comment: You now have two separate definitions of the `Array` struct in your rust source... please post the code that you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue, pointed out by [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283342/adrian), was that I was pushing strings into the Vec.  FFI needs `*const libc::c_char`, which can be converted from a `String`.

```
let mut urls: Vec<*const libc::c_char> = vec![];

urls.push(CString::new(string_var.value.to_string()).unwrap().into_raw());
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `FFI::Pointer#get_array_of_string` is bugged (or it just doesn't do what I think it does). Your code works for me if I change this line:

```
self[:data].get_array_of_string(0, self[:len]).compact
```

to this:

```
Array.new(self[:len]) {|i| self[:data].read_pointer[i * FFI::Pointer::SIZE].read_string }
```

Comment: As a side note, you may want to consider using `std::ffi::CString` instead of `String`

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you Adrian.   And yes CString is what I should have been using.

Comment: One issue though is that I am getting an array of strings only pointing to the first sting in the array.

So I am getting an array that looks like this:

["https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww", "www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww", "le.com/webhp?tab=ww", "ebhp?tab=ww", "=ww", "\t", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

Comment: @mpiccolo I can't imagine why that would be happening. I would recommend posting a new question with a complete example program, the output you are getting, and your expected output. Without that information it is hard to help you.

Comment: I posted the fix above.  You pointed me in the right direction with reminding me I needed a CString instead of a String.